# Magento: Custom Product Search Results (with its own form)

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to generate a search result page with a custom product collection. The plan is to create the product collection based on attributes the customer can choose in a custom html form. I have an **IndexController**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function postAction() {
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/api')->checkPost($postData);
    //$this->_redirect(???);
}
```

which is receiving postData from my form.phtml and passing it to my checkPost function (postData gets evaluated) which returns a custom productCollection. I would like to redirect the customer from the form to a category/search result page with the productCollection as results but I have no idea how to get this done.

Comment: You can find perfect solution for your problem from this source

 http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29023

Comment: @ateam developer This seems like the right way. The prepareProductCollection function in Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer looks like the function I want to override. But I dont know when and where to call it. I also dont know how to call the CatalogSearch query from my custom form submit. Could I dispatch a custom event which triggers my code and then dispatch the "catalogsearch_index_process_start" event?